# Find conditions in which the equation have a real solution $t$ in the interval $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have an equation of the form:
$$αt^{x}+βt^{y}+δt^{z}=0$$ where     $α<0,β<0,δ>0$ are integers and $x>y>z>0$ are also integers.

My **question** is: Find conditions in which this equation have a real solution $t$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a $t$ close enough to 0 so that $f(t)>0$, so sufficient condition is $f(1)<0$.

Lets check if there are solutions when $f(1)\ge 0$, meaning $α+β+δ\ge 0$.

Since $t^{x}<t^{z}$ and $t^{y}<t^{z}$ for $t \in (0,1)$ then $αt^{x}+βt^{y}+δt^{z}>αt^{z}+βt^{z}+δt^{z}\ge 0$

So in this case there are no zeros in the interval.

Therefore $α+β+δ< 0 \Leftrightarrow (\exists t\in(0,1), f(t)=0)$